# Netty: FrameDecoder issue?

Tags: variables, netty

Everyone.

I'm trying to work on a POC for Netty and i've spent 3 hours on my FrameDecoder now. Can't make it work :( The client will send a binary message with this format:

`[Header1] [MessageLength] [Header2] [ActualMessage]`

(e.g. `H0005HWorld`)

The Message length is in decimal format. If the header of the message is `H0255H` then the message length is 255.. I could not use the `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` because it is expecting that the length field is in hex. I also tried using `framedecoder` but i am having problems with it because i can't use the function `channelBuffer.readInt()` to get the length because the length field is in decimal format.

Kindly help me with this :(

Edit:

Tried the basic FrameDecoder and sent the following message: `0005Hello`
The value of the length in the console is `808464436`.. Length should be `5` and not `808464436` right? Kindly enlighten me if i misunderstood something. :(

```
if (channelBuffer.readableBytes() < 4) {
            return null;
         }

channelBuffer.markReaderIndex();

int length = channelBuffer.readInt();
System.out.println(length);

if (channelBuffer.readableBytes() < length) {
 channelBuffer.resetReaderIndex();
 return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Netty doesn't provide a method for reading a decimal number. You can do it yourself easily enough. Here's a quick (non Netty) example of reading the data into a string and then using Integer.parseInt to get the value.

```
byte[] buf = {0,2,5,5};
String s = "";
for(int i=0; i < buf.length; i++) {
    s += buf[i];
}
System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s));
```

Comment: Hi, johnstlr.

did a few modifications on your solution and it worked :) thanks a lot!!!

the incoming data is in hex format so i really do have to convert it to its ascii form and then parse it to its Int value.

`int length =Integer.parseInt(hexToASCII(s.toString()));`